# Friendly URL's with UTF8 characters

Tags: php, utf-8, friendly-url

I'm dealing with creating friendly url's using the title of articles which can be in different languages.

Some languages use characters like 'ä','ü','ö','ß', other characters like cyrillic, accents in spanish words and so on.

The question is that I need to create an URL perfectly understable by browsers and of course google.

Is there any function which manage this?

I'm quite confused in tackling this task.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You need to `urlencode()` the url string. Or to keep it pretty convert them to the non-accent similar character. (ä = a)

Answer (score 0):

Okay do this.

Pass the string as an argument into the inbuilt urlencode("string");

A valid URL is generated

Comment: But, is there any way to sanitize the generated string?

Comment: You can use htmlspecialchars() and html_entity_encode() to covert special characters to their corresponding html entity

Answer (score 0):

At least I could find the solution.

Here is a link of a function that manage this perfectly: https://gist.github.com/sgmurphy/3098978#file-url_slug-php

I hope this help people with the same problem.

Comment: Pointless, when you can use `urlencode()`... Google and Browsers still sees the addresses as if they were decoded.